# Add X509Certificate Tag under KeyInfo Tag Soap Signed Envelope Spring Boot Secruity

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-security, digital-signature

Im trying to add X509Certificate, a public key under KeyInfo Tag while Digitally signing a soap enevelope. I have tried many way, still not look. PFB my Code SNIP and the signed envlope generated.

**CODE SNIP**

```
@Bean
public CryptoFactoryBean getCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword(Constants.JKS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(context.getResource("classpath:certificate/api_cert.p12"));
    return cryptoFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Signature Timestamp");

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementTimeToLive(900000);
    securityInterceptor.setTimestampPrecisionInMilliseconds(true);

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("api.cert");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(Constants.JKS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureDigestAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementMustUnderstand(false);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureParts(
            "{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Content}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp");
    
    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

**GENERATED SIGNED ENVELOPE SNIP**

```
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-1dca42c9-9ff1-463e-a221-cb88577dd3f5">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-5c7abb21-666f-40d2-9f43-ec74f40cc35b">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>8989....</ds:X509SerialNumber>
            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
```

**DESIRED SIGNED ENVELOP SNIP**

```
<KeyInfo>
   <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>MIIGpzCCBY+....</X509Certificate>
      <X509IssuerSerial>
         <X509IssuerName>CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US</X509IssuerName>
         <X509SerialNumber>206281...</X509SerialNumber>
      </X509IssuerSerial>
   </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```